# ./src/index.js Cannot find file: 'App.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\Components'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, import

I have this error:

```
./src/index.js
Cannot find file: 'App.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\Components'.
```

And I've been having a lot of trouble fixing it, I think it has something to do with the import but I'm not exactly sure what it is exactly. In the command prompt it tells me to run  "npm update" But when I do I get an error. I'm just overall confused. Please help..

```
import  { Components } from 'react';

class App extends Components {
    return() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>NFT Marketplace</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

- `Component` not `Components` and
- `render()` for `return()`

  ```
    import { Component } from "react";

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>NFT Marketplace</h1>
          </div>
       );
      }
    }

    export default App;
  ```

Or another way you could write is

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.js this [import App from './App';]is not found. That's why throwing an error.

Plz correct your App.js file:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>NFT Marketplace</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it still produced the same error..

Comment: do you use render()  before returning?

Comment: yes I did use it

Comment: Then follow the answer of @KcH. The typo of Components and render plz.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>NFT Marketplace</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Component` AND `render(){...}`

```
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>NFT Marketplace</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```